# Contrast Enhancement For An Image Using A Gaussian Function

Tags: computer-science

I am working on a program that involves detecting faces in photos, i am reading a paper that someone has wrote and they said that they had more success detecting faces once he they applied some enhancements to the image, one of these being a contrast enhancement. The exact words are...

> Contrast enhancement improves the overall quality of the image. Gaussian convolution using 
>   the Gaussian function G(x, y) is first applied with the input value channel image in the HSV 
>   space. The convolution process can be expressed as follows

They then give you Equation 3: $V_{con} = V_1(x,y) \oplus G(x,y)$ NOTE: $V_1$ is the original value

> $V_{CON}$ in Eq. 3 denotes the convolution result, which contains the luminance information from 
>   the surrounding pixels. The center pixel value is now compared with the Gaussian convolution 
>   result in order to find the amount of contrast enhancement of that center pixel. This process is 
>   described by the following equation

Equation 4: $V_{ce}(x,y) = 255V_{le}(x,y)^{E(x,y)}$ NOTE: $V_{le}$ is the result of another enhancement done previously.

> where $V_{CE}(x, y)$ is the result of contrast enhancement and $E(x, y)$ is given by the following relation

$E(x,y) = (V_{con}(x,y)/V_1(x,y))^g$

> Here g is the image dependent parameter determined by using the standard deviation of the 
>   input value channel image. If the center pixel is brighter then the surrounding pixels, the contrast 
>   of the pixel is pulled up. On the other hand, if the center pixel is darker then the neighboring 
>   pixel then the contrast of the pixel is lowered.

The problem is that with my understanding of maths (NCEA Level 3, Last year at collage) i don't understand how to do the first part, any help would be much appreciated

The full paper is here: http://jips-k.org/dlibrary/JIPS_v09_no1_paper9.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a convolution product for $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions is the following :
$$ f \otimes g : x \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) g(x-y) dy $$

Since you're dealing with $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued functions,
$$ V_1 \otimes G : (x,y) \mapsto \int_{[0,w]\times[0,h]} V_1(x', y') G(x-x', y-y') dx' dy' $$
assuming $V_1$'s support is $[0, w]\times[0,h]$ : your picture's dimensions.

Now, the gaussian function associated to $(m, \sigma) \in \mathbb{R}\times $ (resp. $(M, \Sigma) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $) is defined as
$$
   \begin{aligned}
      & G_{m, \sigma} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left( -\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \\
      & G_{M, \Sigma} :X \mapsto \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{det(\Sigma)}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} {}^t (X-M) \Sigma (X-M) \right)
   \end{aligned}
$$

Though it is not justified in the article and I am no expert in image processing, I believe the point of this operation is to **locally smoothe your picture's contrast**. These facts may help you understand it
$$
   \begin{aligned}
      & f \otimes \delta_a (x) = f(x-a) \\
      & \lim_{\sigma \to 0} G_\sigma = \delta_{0}    \hspace{3cm}\text{(in the sense of distributions)}
   \end{aligned}
$$
Since you deal with pixels, **your convolution product is but a weighted sum of contrast in the vicinity of a given pixel**. $M$ should definitely be set to $0$, and $\Sigma$ (which has most likely been set to $1_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ by the authors) defines how "local" the smoothing is.